# ping command not giving IP address when connected to mobile hotspot

Tags: linux, networking, client-server

I observed one thing while learning about "ping" command. When your pc is connected to internet via wifi it gives the IP address of the domain name.

```
ping google.in

Pinging google.in [142.250.192.68] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 142.250.192.68: bytes=32 time=70ms TTL=117
Reply from 142.250.192.68: bytes=32 time=60ms TTL=117
Reply from 142.250.192.68: bytes=32 time=60ms TTL=117
Reply from 142.250.192.68: bytes=32 time=56ms TTL=117
```

However when your pc is connected to internet via mobile hotspot it gives

```
ping google.in

Pinging google.in [2404:6888:4009:82a::2004] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 2404:6888:4009:82a::2004: time=132ms
Reply from 2404:6888:4009:82a::2004: time=66ms
Reply from 2404:6888:4009:82a::2004: time=39ms
Reply from 2404:6888:4009:82a::2004: time=56ms
```

Can someone explain why this happens?

Comment: `ping -4 google.in`

Comment: mobile networks are ipv6 since most ipv4 are used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first example shows IPv4 addresses, whereas the second shows IPv6 addresses.  Here is your chance to learn IPv6, including understanding how/why v4/v6 is used in this example!